# Getting Timeout error(504) from an https POST endpoint in swagger-ui

Tags: https, graphql, apollo-server, node-fetch, graphql-mutation

I am using POST api built by different team in our application and since its taking more than 1 minute to return a response our graphql mutation is returning Internal_Server_error (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/data/errors#internal_server_error). We are using @types/node-fetch: "1.6.9" to consume these endpoints. I tried to set the timeout in the options  object of the request as mentioned in github (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node-fetch/index.d.ts#L59) but Apollo server is still giving Internal_Server_Error. I tried using AbortController but our application is currently using Node 12.x.x and abort controller requires node 14.x.x.

I just want to know if there is anything we can do from our end to make apollo server wait for the request to be successful which should take 1 minute and 10 seconds and not give out 504.

This is how I am setting  the timeout

```
   import fetch from "node-fetch";

   const res = await fetch(`${this.baseURL}/api/v1/dummy?${query}`,
     {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
       -----
       -----
      }),
      timeout: 60000,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    });
```

Value of res variable after running the mutation:

```
 Body {
  url: 'secret_url',
  status: 504,
  statusText: 'Gateway Time-out',
  headers: Headers {
    _headers: {
      server: [Array],
      date: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      connection: [Array],
      'set-cookie': [Array]
    }
  },
  ok: false,
  body: PassThrough {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 1 },
      length: 132,
      pipes: null,
      pipesCount: 0,
      flowing: null,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    readable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { prefinish: [Function: prefinish] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: true,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: true,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _transformState: {
      afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
      needTransform: false,
      transforming: false,
      writecb: null,
      writechunk: null,
      writeencoding: 'buffer'
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  bodyUsed: false,
  size: 0,
  timeout: 180000,
  _raw: [],
  _abort: false
}
```

Response from swagger-ui

[swagger-ui response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChF5l.png)